# How to get data when I click cart button in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I am new in Yii2, I have a problem to get data from another table when button clicked, for example: similar with shopping web, when I click "order", then I will go to order page and I dont need to fill my name, stuff and another, it will be fill automatically.
I have 2 table

1. kntn_menu_paket

   - menu_paket_id (PK)
   - nama_menu_paket
   - harga
   - gambar
   - status_menu
2. kntn_r_pesanan

   - pesanan_id (PK)
   - menu_paket_id (FK)
   - tgl_pengambilan

`kntn_menu_paket(model)`

```
class KntnMenuPaket extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * behaviour to add created_at and updatet_at field with current datetime (timestamp)
     * and created_by and updated_by field with current user id (blameable)
     */
    public function behaviors(){
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            ],
            'blameable' => [
                'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
            ],
            'del' => [
                'class' => DeleteBehavior::className(),
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'kntn_menu_paket';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['harga', 'nama_menu_paket','deskripsi'], 'required'],
            [['harga', 'deleted'], 'integer'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'], 'safe'],
            [['nama_menu_paket', 'created_by', 'updated_by','deskripsi','status_menu','harga'], 'string', 'max' => 1000],
            [['gambar'], 'file','extensions' =>'jpeg, jpg, png, gif'],
            [['deleted_by'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'harga' => 'Harga',
            'menu_paket_id' => 'Menu Paket ID',
            'nama_menu_paket' => 'Nama Menu Paket',
            'gambar' => 'Gambar',
            'deskripsi' =>'Deskripsi',
            'status_menu'=>'Status Makanan',
            //..
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getKntnRPesanans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(KntnRPesanan::className(), ['menu_paket_id' => 'menu_paket_id']);
    }
}
```

`kntn_r_pesanan(model)`

```
class KntnRPesanan extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * behaviour to add created_at and updatet_at field with current datetime (timestamp)
     * and created_by and updated_by field with current user id (blameable)
     */
    public function behaviors(){
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            ],
            'blameable' => [
                'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
            ],
            'delete' => [
                'class' => DeleteBehavior::className(),
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'kntn_r_pesanan';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['tgl_pengambilan', 'jlh_pesanan', 'acara', 'alamat', 'menu_paket_id', 'status_pesanan'], 'required'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'], 'safe'],
            [['deleted', 'menu_paket_id'], 'integer'],
            [['tgl_pengambilan', 'jlh_pesanan', 'acara', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['alamat'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
            [['deleted_by'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['status_pesanan'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['menu_paket_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => KntnMenuPaket::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['menu_paket_id' => 'menu_paket_id']]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'pesanan_id' => 'Pesanan ID',
            'tgl_pengambilan' => 'Tgl Pengambilan',
            'jlh_pesanan' => 'Jlh Pesanan',
      //..
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getMenuPaket()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(KntnMenuPaket::className(), ['menu_paket_id' => 'menu_paket_id']);
    }

}
```

`kntn_r_pesanan/index`

```
<div class="kntn-r-pesanan-indexuser">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>


    <p>
        <?= Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"> Pesananku</i>', ['kntn-r-pesanan/history'], ['class' => 'btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-chart'])?>
    </p>



    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            //'harga',


            [
                'attribute' => 'harga',
                'filter' => '',
                'value' => function($model){
                    return "Rp".number_format($model->harga,2,',','.');
                },
            ],

            //'menu_paket_id',
            'nama_menu_paket',

            [
                'attribute' => 'gambar',
                'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
            ],
            //'created_at',
            'deskripsi',
            'status_menu',
            // 'updated_at',
            // 'created_by',
            // 'updated_by',
            // 'deleted',
            // 'deleted_at',
            // 'deleted_by',

            ['class' => 'common\components\ToolsColumn',
                'template'=>'{view} {edit} {del} {cart}',
                'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index){
                    if ($action === 'view') {
                        return Url::toRoute(['view', 'id' => $key]);
                    }
                    if ($action === 'edit') {
                        return Url::toRoute(['edit', 'id' => $key]);
                    }
                    if ($action === 'del') {
                        return Url::toRoute(['delete', 'id' => $key]);
                    }
                    if($action ==='cart'){
                        return Url::toRoute(['cart', 'id'=>$key]);
                    }
                }
            ],

        ],
    ]); ?>
```

When I click chart Button, then I'll go to _form, and `nama_menu_paket` will retrieve from this index

`kntn_r_pesanan(_form)`

```
<div class="kntn-r-pesanan-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'menu_paket_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <!--<?= $form->field($model, 'tgl_pengambilan')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>-->


    <?= $form->field($model, 'jlh_pesanan')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'acara')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'alamat')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>



    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Tambah' : 'Edit', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you just need to automatically fill some of the form's fields.

So you just need to go in the controller action which renders your form and set the model's fields with data from the other table/model. You do that just by setting model fields before the view is being rendered.

```
$model->your_field = $otherModel->other_field;
```